# Wordpress custom post type listing not showing the correct number of items & pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, listing

I'm using Custom Post Type UI plugin by WebDevStudios to create custom post type. However, in the admin view custom post type listing, its not showing the correct number of items & also not showing pagination. This doesn't happen in other environments, only specific to 1 environment. Not sure what I did wrong. Anyone knows how to fix this? Was it in configuration somewhere?

Other note, there's no code written to display the listing, its all using plugin, and this issue only happens to custom post types, but not on pages listing.

[image: There's 371 FAQs, but its showing 3 items on the right side, and no pagination. The listing is set to display 25 items per page]

Comment: This question is heavily related to a plugin. Please contact the author of the plugin, who is technically closer to your question and might be more helpful.